# in C#, msgbox didn't show

Tags: msgbox

Below is part of my codes in C#, it suppose to send email, show the msg box, then direct to 'Multihotelbook.aspx'  page, but the direct to the page without showing the msgbox. i dont know why. need help

emailClient.Send(message);

```
                // Response.Write("<script>window.alert('Email sent')</script>");
                //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "myscript", "<script>alert('Email sent');</script>");
                // System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Email sent");
               // MessageBox.Show("Email sent");
               // MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Email sent", "Confirmation");


            //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "myscript", "<script>alert('Email sent');</script>");
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Message", "confirm('Email sent');", true);
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "KEY", "alert('Email sent')", true);
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "alert", "<script>alert('Email sent')</script>");
            Response.Redirect("Multihotelbook.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

This... looks like ASP.NET code.  There is no `MessageBox` in ASP.NET.  Notice that you had to fully reference `System.Windows.Forms`, which I imagine you also had to add as a reference.  Windows Forms and ASP.NET are two *very* different things.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Showing a JavaScript `alert()`?  If that's the case then you can just include some additional JavaScript code in the response.

Except... you're also doing this:

```
Response.Redirect("Multihotelbook.aspx");
```

Which means that the response to the client is being clobbered by a header which tells the client to go to `Multihotelbook.aspx`.  So the client never sees anything else you're including in the response, basically anything in `RegisterStartupScript`.

After this code executes, the client is going to end up on `Multihotelbook.aspx`.  Unless there's a JavaScript `alert()` on that page, the browser won't show one.

One approach you could try is to pass a flag to `Multihotelbook.aspx`, something like `Multihotelbook.aspx?emailSent=true` and in the `Page_Load` of that page check for that value and, if it's set to true, include JavaScript code in the page to show the `alert()` (probably using `RegisterStartupScript` like you're already trying).

Comment: Hi David, thx for ur answer and suggestion. i found the answer to perform both msgbox and redirect to Multihotelbook.aspx

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "myScript", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Email(s) Sent');window.location='Multihotelbook.aspx';</script>");